# Eliminar Puntos negros en imagen Blanco y Negro, Python(OpenCV)

Tags: python, imagen, numpy, opencv

Quisiera que me orientaran en el siguiente problema.

1.Tengo una imagen, que ha sido transformada a Blanco y Negro y se le ha pasado un filtro gaussiano.
2.Esta imagen luego le he aplicado la función **cv2.adaptiveThreshold**
3.El resultado luego de ello es una imagen a blanco y negro(llamada **dst**), en la que deseo eliminar, los puntitos negros redundantes(**rojo**), por así decirlo, sin embargo no quisiera eliminar aquellos que pertenecen a una grieta(**azul*) pues pienso almacenarlas luego en la función contourns.
4.Muchas gracias de antemano, y espero me haya explicado bien

EDIT:He ñadido la funcion opening,y ha mejorado un poco(imagen 2) no es el resudado optimo que me gustaría pero va por ahi al cosa,si alguien me orientaria que mas podría aplicarle, me ayudaría muchisimo. HE añadido el código escrito a sugerencia de un usuaro.

[image: Imagen original a ByN]

[image: Paso de la izquiera a la derecha]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Cargamos la imagen

# Nombre de la imagen
nombre_imagen="columna"
# Formato
formato=".png"

# Ruta de la Carpeta que contiene la imagen original
ruta_entrada="C:/Users/MARTIN/Desktop/proyecto_grietas/Input/"


# Cargamos la imagen y la almacenamos en la variable: "imagen"

original = cv2.imread(ruta_entrada+nombre_imagen+formato)

cv2.imshow("original", original)

 
# Convertimos a escala de grises
gris = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 
# Aplicar suavizado Gaussiano
gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(gris, (5,5), 0)  # El tamaño de la máscara debe ser impar.  
 
#cv2.imshow("Gauss", gauss)


dst = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gauss,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)


ret,dst2 = cv2.threshold(dst,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imshow("R1", dst2)

# Eliminando puntos negros con erosdion y dilatacion

kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)

dst3 = cv2.morphologyEx(dst2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

cv2.imshow("R2", dst3)

################################################

### Detectamos los bordes con Canny

canny = cv2.Canny(dst3.copy(),50,100)

#cv2.imshow("canny", canny)

# Buscamos los contornos

(contornos1,_) = cv2.findContours((canny), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  


original1=original.copy()

cv2.drawContours(original1,contornos1,-1,(0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow(" Rf ", original1)

 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Publica el código como texto, no imagen. Asi podremos leerlo, copiarlo y probarlo en otras máquinas.

Comment: Carlos, haz hecho, lo que se conoce como vandalizar tu propia pregunta, si no debiera estar en el sitio, puedes eliminarla directamente. Por cualquier otro tema contacta a los moderadores. Saludos

Comment: Tiene pinta de que deberías haber hecho algún preproceso (filtro de mediana, o bilateral, u otros) antes de binarizar. Ayudaría ver la imagen original, antes de binarizarla.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!